# Escaping chars in f-string

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I have run into the following issue with the `f-string`:

```
>>> a='hello'

# how to print '{hello}' ?

>>> f'{{a}}'
'{a}'

>>> f'\{{a}\}'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: f-string: single '}' is not allowed

# doing it without f-strings
>>> '{' + a + '}'
'{hello}'
```

How do I escape chars in an fstring?

Comment: Double braces become a single brace on output, and you want the normal action of braces too, so try triple braces - `f'{{{a}}}'`.

Answer (score 10):

You need *triple* braces:

```
f'{{{a}}}'
```

The two outer `{}`s "escape" and evaluate to `{...}`, then the inner `{}` is used for formatting (or at least that's how I interpret it).