# escape single bracket in f-string

Tags: python, f-string

I am trying to print a string in the following format:

```
"rob: {color: red  , number: 4}"
```

using an f-string to fill three values:

```
f"{name}: color: {color}  , number: {number}" #missing brackets
```

this would print:

```
"rob: color: red  , number: 4" #missing brackets
```

but I have no idea how to escape a single bracket the way I need to. I know `{{}}` lets you escape brackets, but this would print both at the same place in the string. I tried `{ { }` and `{ } }` in their respective spots but this just threw an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping chars in f-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58667472/escaping-chars-in-f-string)

Comment: Escaping an `{` is just a repeated brace, e.g. `{{`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goal:

```
"rob: {color: red  , number: 4}"
```

Accomplished:

```
>>> name = 'rob'
>>> color = 'red'
>>> number = 4
>>> print(f"{name}: {{color: {color} , number: {number}}}")
rob: {color: red , number: 4}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use double brackets when you want to show them, and single brackers for variables. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo)

```
f"{name}: {{color: {color}  , number: {number} }}"
```

Comment: Changed my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can evaluate the string literal `'{'` and the string literal `'}'` inside the f-string, by wrapping them with braces to do the evaluation:

```py
f"{name}: {'{'}color: {color}, number: {number}{'}'}"
```

Example:

```py
>>> name = 'bob'
>>> color = 'red'
>>> number = 4
>>> f"{name}: {'{'}color: {color}, number: {number}{'}'}"
'bob: {color: red, number: 4}'
```